# Custom UIView label and animation not showing up in view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3

I actually have a custom uiview that works, and I think everything in the uiview that doesn't work is set up the same as the one that works.  Here is the code:

```
protocol SessionDisplayViewDelegate: class
{
     func homeButtonTapped()
}

class SessionDisplayView: UIView 
{

@IBOutlet var view: UIView!


@IBOutlet weak var accountImage: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var mySKView: SKView!
@IBOutlet weak var sessionTitle: UILabel!

weak var delegate: SessionDisplayViewDelegate?
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    commonInitialization()

}

override init(frame: CGRect)  {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInitialization()
}

func commonInitialization()
{
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SessionDisplayView", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.addSubview(self.view)


    //accountImage = UIImage(data: ShareData.sharedInstance.accounts[ShareData.sharedInstance.indexOfCurrentAccount].picture!, scale: 1.0)

}

func onView()
{
    let curScene = MyScene(size: mySKView.bounds.size)
    curScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
    mySKView.presentScene(curScene)
    let myImage = UIImage(data: (ShareData.sharedInstance.accounts[ShareData.sharedInstance.indexOfCurrentAccount]?.picture!)! as Data, scale: 0.5)

    accountImage.setImage(myImage, for: UIControlState())
    sessionTitle.text = ShareData.sharedInstance.accounts[ShareData.sharedInstance.indexOfCurrentAccount]?.name
    var myTest = sessionTitle.text
    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()

 }

@IBAction func homeButtonTouched(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    delegate?.homeButtonTapped()
}
}
```

I don't know that the self.view.setNeedsDisplay() needs to be called- I'm just trying to make it work.  The title doesn't change even though the variable for the title does change- I've checked that, and that is working.  Either there's a connection issue between the label and the variable, or the view controller isn't getting the update signal to change the view controller.  I don't know which- and I don't know how to nail down which it is, either.  Any ideas on how to fix this would be deeply appreciated.  Here is the ViewController code:

```
class SessionDisplayViewController: UIViewController, SessionDisplayViewDelegate
{

@IBOutlet weak var mySessionView: SessionDisplayView!
func homeButtonTapped()
{
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ReturnHome", sender: self)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    mySessionView.onView()
    mySessionView.sessionTitle.text = "Test"

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override var shouldAutorotate : Bool {
    if (UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft) || (UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight) || (UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.unknown)
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portraitUpsideDown]
}
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}
}
```

Any thoughts or suggestion on how to get the UIView to update would be most welcome.  Thanks.

Sincerely,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

How does you add your custom view to your root view? From code or from xib/storyboard? If you done that by xib/storyboard you must override `awakeFromNib` method in your custom view class and call `commonInitialization` inside it. init() method was call only if you create your view by code.

Comment: I tried this and it did not help.  It turns out somehow the view controller got corrupted- I deleted it and recreated it, and it worked.  I don't know why though.